# How to set default java opts in hadoop without being overlapped at runtime

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I intend to set the default gc collector to `-XX:+UseSerialGC` when running YARN application.

I've tried to set this parameter in hadoop-env.sh, neither to `HADOOP_OPTS` nor `HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS` did it work:

```
//hadoop-env.sh
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts='-XX:+UseSerialGC'"
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-XX:+UseSerialGC $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"
```

Likewise, when setting it in mapred-site.xml as below, it turns out to be overlapped when I run hadoop task via `hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar pi -Dmapreduce.map.java.opts="-Xmx256M" 4 1000`, in which the rumtime parameter '-Dmapreduce.map.java.opts' overrides what have configured in mapred-site.xml.

```
//mapred-site.xml
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx1024M -XX:+UseSerialGC</value>
</property>
```

The way that I check out whether the parameter takes effect is by login to a DataNode and issue command:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_11/bin/jps -mlv | grep -i gc
```

Is there any solutions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that property is read-only and couldn't overridden by using **final** like this:

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx1024M -XX:+UseSerialGC</value>
  <final>true</final>
</property>
```